# Sending image through socket python

Tags: python, sockets, buffer

I'm fairly new to python and I have to send a screenshot taken through the servers computer to the client. I've been reading around and everyone is saying to use the buffer but I don't really understand how the buffer works. What I have so far:

Server side:

```
current_socket.send(open(r"*file location*", "rb").read())
```

Client side:

```
data = my_socket.recv(2048)
buff = StringIO.StringIO(data)
img = Image.open(buff)
img.show()
```

When it opens the image all I get is a black picture.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: ...are you sure the image isn't larger than 2048 bytes?

Comment: thats a possibility, how can I check?

Comment: @eitanmayer. How about `print(len(data))`? (On the server side). PS: or just print the result of `send`, which is the number of bytes it actually sent.

Comment: You were right! turns out the image was a lot bigger and once I increased the receiving socket size it worked :)